# How to get numbers from content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get only numbers from the div content without using plugins?

```
<div class='test'>
test 123
</div>
```

How to get 123?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
var num = $('.test').text().replace(/\D/g, '');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var abc= $(".test").html();
var numberArray = abc.split(" ");
```

value of numberArray[0] will be abc and numberArray[1] will be 123.

Use split function to split a string at desired point. Here we use abc.split(" "); means to split the string whenever you see a space.